Issues Integrating USMPO API with Our Moving Services Application
I'm encountering difficulties while integrating the US Moving Protection Organization (USMPO) https://usmpo.org/ API with our in-house moving services application. Here is a detailed description of the problem:
Problem Description:
We are attempting to use the USMPO API to automate the addition of moving leads into our application. The goal is to ensure seamless data transfer and real-time updates. However, we are facing issues with authentication and data retrieval.
Steps Taken:
Registered our application with the USMPO to obtain API credentials.
Configured the API endpoints and included the provided credentials.
Implemented the necessary API calls for data retrieval and submission.
Expected Outcome:
We expected the API to authenticate successfully and return data on moving leads that we can process within our application.
Actual Outcome:
The API calls are failing with an "Unauthorized" error message, despite using the correct credentials. Additionally, on the rare occasions when authentication is successful, the data returned is incomplete or incorrectly formatted.
I have ensured that the API credentials are correct and have tried re-generating them multiple times. I have also tested the API calls using tools like Postman to rule out issues with our application code. Despite these efforts, the issues persist.
Has anyone successfully integrated the USMPO API with their applications? What steps or configurations are necessary to ensure smooth authentication and accurate data retrieval?
Final Check:
